# Cloud Endpoint URL in cron.xml App Engine

Tags: cron, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to set up a cron job in App Engine that executes a GET request over a Cloud Endpoint method.

I've created the GET method in an Endpoint class with the @API annotation

```
@ApiMethod(name = "cron.test", path="cron/test", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public void testCron() {
    ... // do something
}
```

In cron.xml I've set:

```
<cronentries>
 <cron>
  <url>/_ah/api/MYAPI/v1/cron/test</url>
  <description>Send nightly reports.</description>
  <schedule>every 1 minutes</schedule>
  <timezone>America/Los_Angeles</timezone>
 </cron>
</cronentries>
```

Cron Jobs view in App Engine admin panel shows that the cron tries to execute but fails. What am I doing wrong? Is the URL to the endpoint method wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs under `/_ah/api` are not owned by your application, they are owned by Google's API infrastructure, and so your application won't receive those requests.

A few things to consider:

- Abstract the behavior into a helper method and call that in your cron handler
- Use the `/_ah/spi` handler you've defined directly

PS In the future, it'd be helpful to also include any errors from your logs or not that you didn't see any (which is almost certainly going to be true here, for reasons mentioned above).

Comment: bossylobster, can you give some sample for calling endpoint method from cron?